# Multiple insert text field with the same ID or Name

Tags: javascript

I want insert multiple form by ID or Name. So I try `var txt_bw = document.getElementsByName('before_wash').value;` it not work and I try `var txt_bw = document.getElementById('before_wash').value;` be an error because have the same ID in one form.

Thank you!

I've already use `document.getElementsByName` `document.getElementsById` `document.getElementsByClassName` but it not work at all.

Comment: [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique across the DOM. If you want multiples use a `class`.

Comment: hi @pilchard thank you for response my question. Yes, that true I've already have unique id. But when textbox looping, the id is error because duplicate

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including a sample of your HTML as well as the actual js that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

element IDs should be unique within the entire document, but you can reuse the same name for your forms.

As you already used getElementByName I think you can still try to use it like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('before_wash');
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    values.push(elements[i].value);
}
console.log(values);
```

You can also try document.querySelectorAll

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name="before_wash"]');
```

Comment: Hi @Alin thank you for responese my question. I've already try it but still not work. Just ``getElementById`` can work but when I input second field the result not show